# Node.js + Cheerio Scraping : How to post in a contact form?

Tags: html, web, cheerio

I  am pretty new to web scraping techniques though I already have solid knowledge in terms of PHP / HTML / CSS.

After reading a few tutorials and a lot of tries, I finally managed to scrape my first results as a test.

I use Cheerio + Node.js, and here was the code of my test:

```html
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

request('http://www.passion-de-vin.com/contact/', function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var parsedResults = [];
        $('.form-headline').filter(function(i, element) {
            var a = $(this).children();
            var titre = a.first().text();
            release2 = titre.replace(/(\r?\n)/g, '');
            release = release2.replace(/\s\s/g, '');
            titre = titre;            

            // Our parsed meta data object
            var metadata = {
                titre,
            };

            // Push meta-data into parsedResults array
            parsedResults.push(metadata);

            fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(parsedResults, null, 4), function(err){

            console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');})
        });
        // Log our finished parse results in the terminal
        console.log(parsedResults);
    }
});
```

I have the result log in my JSON file.

Now I would like to know and understand how I can transmit information to that form, post a result and see or get the result of the post.

So far, all I have read has been unclear to me

Comment: You probably want to use nightmare or puppeteer for that.

Comment: Thanks. Any tutorial ?

Comment: just google for nightmare scraping.

Comment: This isn't related to Cheerio. Cheerio is just an HTML parser, so it can extract data but it can't submit forms or in any way interact with a page. Use a browser automation package like Puppeteer or an HTTP request library like axios, depending on the nature of the site and the form you want to submit.